# Drawing many circles to form a larger shape

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, html5-canvas

I'm making a project using canvas and svg. I've drawn a pattern using canvas with 4 Circles and in each 4 circles there's one inner circle. The problem is, I now need to make those 4 circles and inner circles smaller in order to insert more of them, up to 30, on my screen. Here's my code.

```
function telaCirculos(x,y,r,angIn,angFim,corFundo,corLinha){
    pintor.fillStyle=corFundo;
    pintor.strokeStyle=corLinha;
    pintor.beginPath();
    pintor.arc(x,y,r,angIn,angFim);
    pintor.closePath();
    pintor.stroke(); pintor.fill();
}
```

then I just call my function in the script like so:

```
telaCirculos(250,500,250,Math.PI,-2*Math.PI,"#449779","#449779");
telaCirculos(250,500,200,Math.PI,-2*Math.PI,"#013D55","#013D55");
telaCirculos(500,250,250,Math.PI/2,3*Math.PI/2,"#E6B569","#E6B569");
telaCirculos(500,250,200,Math.PI/2,3*Math.PI/2,"#AA8D49","#AA8D49");
telaCirculos(0,250,250,Math.PI/2,-3*Math.PI/2,"#E6B569","#E6B569");
telaCirculos(0,250,200,Math.PI/2,-3*Math.PI/2,"#AA8D49","#AA8D49");
telaCirculos(250,0,250,0,-Math.PI,"#449779","#449779");
telaCirculos(250,0,200,0,-Math.PI,"#013D55","#013D55");
```

This draws the circles with my desired coordinates. Now I need to fill my screen with more of these. I'll post some screenshots.

What I have done:

[image]

What I need to do:

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look at the canvas arc method signature and what every parameter is for?

Comment: What do you mean "insert more of them"? do you need to tile the image? or draw smaller circles inside the circles you have?

Comment: yes, i need to tile the image and scale it in order to put up to 30 tiles vertically and horizontally.

P.S:Sorry, it's my first time coding in HTML!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to GameAlchemist's solution, is to think of the pattern as rows and columns of circles. You can use nested loops to draw the rows and columns of circles. Each row partially overlaps the previous row by half a circle. Every other row offset is horizonally offset by half a circle. Since rows overlap, each row covers a vertical distance of radius. To compute number of rows, you basically divide height by radius. Since the columns do not overlap, each column covers a horizonal distance of 2 * radius. To compute number of columns, you basically divide width by radius. Since the first circle can be half outside the area being painting, you actually have to add radius to height and width before dividing by 2 * radius and radius, respectively. You can use arrays to hold the colors and offsets. Then the function to fill a rectangular area with circles could look like...

```
function drawCircles(x, y, width, height, outerRadius, innerRadius) {
    var outerColors = ["#449779", "#E6B569"];
    var innerColors = ["#013d55", "#AA8D49"];
    var offsets = [0, outerRadius];
    var startAngle = 0;
    var endAngle = 2 * Math.PI;
    var iMax = (width + outerRadius) / (outerRadius);
    for (i = 0; i < iMax; i++) {
        var outerColor = outerColors[i % outerColors.length];
        var innerColor = innerColors[i % innerColors.length];;
        var offset = offsets[i % offsets.length];
        var jMax = (height + outerRadius - offset) / (2 * outerRadius);
        for (j = 0; j < jMax; j++) {
            var cx = x + j * 2 * outerRadius + offset;
            var cy = y + height - i * outerRadius;
            telaCirculos(cx, cy, outerRadius, startAngle, endAngle, outerColor, outerColor)
            telaCirculos(cx, cy, innerRadius, startAngle, endAngle, innerColor, innerColor);
        }
    }
}
```

You would then call the function with the dimensions of the canvas and the desired size of circles...

```
var outerRadius = canvasWidth / numberOfCircles;
var innerRadius = 0.8 * outerRadius;
drawCircles(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, outerRadius, innerRadius);
```

Comment: Please make a snippet out of it (borrow what you want from mine), i'm curious to see if the antialiasing makes it look better than a pattern fill.

Answer (score 0):

Your best take here is to create a pattern out of your circle, then to fill your main canvas with that pattern.

To do that, create a temporary canvas on which you draw your pattern then create a `pattern` out of it.

```js
document.body.style.margin = 0;
var cv = document.getElementById('cv');
var mainContext = cv.getContext('2d');

var canvasWidth;
var canvasHeight;

function update() {
  canvasWidth = cv.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvasHeight = cv.height = window.innerHeight;
  drawCircles();
}

update();

window.onresize = update;

function drawCircles() {
  mainContext.save();
  // full screen rect
  mainContext.rect(0, 0,
    mainContext.canvas.width, mainContext.canvas.height);
  // scale to put more circles inside ( :-) )
  mainContext.scale(1 / 10, 1 / 10);
  mainContext.fillStyle = buildPattern();
  mainContext.fill();
  mainContext.restore();
}

function buildPattern() {
  var tempCv = document.createElement('canvas');
  tempCv.width = 500;
  tempCv.height = 500;
  var pintor = tempCv.getContext('2d');

  telaCirculos(250, 500, 250, Math.PI, -2 * Math.PI, "#449779", "#449779");
  telaCirculos(250, 500, 200, Math.PI, -2 * Math.PI, "#013D55", "#013D55");
  telaCirculos(500, 250, 250, Math.PI / 2, 3 * Math.PI / 2, "#E6B569", "#E6B569");
  telaCirculos(500, 250, 200, Math.PI / 2, 3 * Math.PI / 2, "#AA8D49", "#AA8D49");
  telaCirculos(0, 250, 250, Math.PI / 2, -3 * Math.PI / 2, "#E6B569", "#E6B569");
  telaCirculos(0, 250, 200, Math.PI / 2, -3 * Math.PI / 2, "#AA8D49", "#AA8D49");
  telaCirculos(250, 0, 250, 0, -Math.PI, "#449779", "#449779");
  telaCirculos(250, 0, 200, 0, -Math.PI, "#013D55", "#013D55");

  var pattern = pintor.createPattern(tempCv, 'repeat');

  return pattern;

  function telaCirculos(x, y, r, angIn, angFim, corFundo, corLinha) {
    pintor.fillStyle = corFundo;
    pintor.strokeStyle = corLinha;
    pintor.beginPath();
    pintor.arc(x, y, r, angIn, angFim);
    pintor.closePath();
    pintor.stroke();
    pintor.fill();
  }

}
```

```html
<canvas id='cv'></canvas>
```